# Prove that the lemniscate is not a smooth manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

> Let $M$ be the lemniscate $y^2=4x^2-4x^4$:
>
> [image]
>
> I want to show that $M$ cannot be a smooth manifold.

Consider $M$ with the topology that makes $M$ a topological subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. It is pretty clear that $M$ cannot admit a local chart around the point $(0,0)$. If so, a neighborhood of $U=B_\varepsilon(0,0)\cap M$ should be homeomorphic to some open interval $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R$. If we remove the point $(0,0)$ from $U$ and $\varphi(0,0)$ from $(a,b)$, we get that $U-\{(0,0)\}$ has four connected components and $(a,b)-\{\varphi(0,0)\}$ has only two connected components.

This proves that $M$ with the topology induced by $\mathbb R^2$ cannot be a smooth manifold.

**My question is:** How can I show that $M$ is not a manifold for any topology in $M$?

Comment: You can't. It's not true.

Comment: It is not hard to find a bijection from $M$ to $(0,1)$ so it is unclear what you mean with "any topology in $M$".

Answer (score 1):

There exists a topology in which the space you’re talking about is infact a manifold. Once you find a bijection to an open set, you can then transfer the manifold structure.

Comment: OP already understands that $M$ with it's usual topology is not a manifold. This writing of $M = S^1 \vee S^1$ assumes that topology. The question is regarding changing the topology on $M$.